# How should I connect Bosch wall oven wires which have crimped-on posts?

Tags: wiring, oven

I am replacing an existing Kenmore wall oven with a new Bosch oven. Both are four wires. It seemed easy enough to me. Just remove the crimp/sleeve off the old wire and then use some wire nuts to connect the new oven inside the junction box: red to red, black to black, white to white, green to green.

I set out to do this and discovered that the new oven has some sort of connectors crimped at the ends of the wires. I can cut and strip these wires but I have a feeling that is not preferred way to do this as Bosch has some other idea. How do I connect this?

Added details: The instructions show it being connected inside a junction box with wire nuts. This is a single oven. Here is the manual. See page 8 for wiring:

https://assets.ajmadison.com/ajmadison/itemdocs/HBE5453UC-install.pdf

[image: See photo attached of new oven pigtail]

Comment: Have you referred to the instructions that came with the oven?

Comment: The instructions seem to show that type of wire being connected to the junction box on top of the oven for a top/bottom oven.  Do you have a single oven, or a double type?

Comment: It is a single oven. Where do you see anything about a top/bottom oven in the instructions?

Comment: Just remove the [old wire nuts] off the old wire and then [re-use them]. If it's "crimp/sleeve", it gets cut off because that's not how I do it if it isn't an RV. "He said he was not allowed to give installation advice" for a *field modification*, yeah, you bet. Except that's what you do here, and it puts the onus on your electrician. It comes like that so that it doesn't have to be a different production run if you only buy the lower oven. As with a lot of things, you throw away the crap they give you, and do it right. Which is a UL approved connector, that is available at your store.

Answer (score 0):

Those wire ends seem to be designed for using euro-style electrical terminal blocks, with the set screws. Those connectors are readily available in the US, and are what I would use, instead of cutting the existing ends off and using wire nuts.

Comment: I looked at those but I am not sure which ones take those double solid wires. Also, the conduit coming out of the wall is a single solid wire so I would need a terminal that takes both.  Maybe I just need to go to an electrical supply.

Comment: By the way, I called Bosch and the tech on the phone said it looked like the wiring to connect a top oven to a bottom oven. However, he then pulled up the part number for my oven and said that is indeed the correct cabling.  He said he was not allowed to give installation advice other than to contact a certified Bosch appliance installer.

Comment: I went to two different electrical supply houses and they had no clue.